# how to check if a site has enabled Cache-Control for a file type

Tags: caching, cache-control

I was wondering if there is any way to check if a website has enabled `Cache-Control` for a file type and its expiry time
example for
http://foo.com/foo.css
how can i know if Cache-Control is enabled for it and whats is the expiry time set for it

Comment: CURL, get headers only, see if `expires` is set?

Comment: can you please explain how to do it ?

Comment: Check my answer. Replace the `$url` with any url of your choice. If the page sends a `Expires` header, it will echo the expiry time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
<?php
$temp = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $temp, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://foo.com/foo.css' );
curl_setopt( $temp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $temp, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
curl_setopt( $temp, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $temp, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
echo curl_exec( $temp );
curl_close( $temp );
?>
```

*This will return an output like This:*

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Date: ***Current Date*** GMT
>   Content-Type: text/css Content-Length: 2713 Connection: keep-alive
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Last-Modified: **Date of file creation**
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes Cache-Control: max-age=***expiry time in sec set for it***
>   Expires: **Expiry Date** GMT

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url    = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19320848/how-to-check-if-a-site-has-enabled-cache-control-for-a-file-type';

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );

$res    = explode( "\n", curl_exec( $ch ) );

foreach( $res as $line ) {
    if( strpos( $line, 'Expires:' ) !== false ) {
        $line = explode( ':', $line );

        array_shift( $line );
        echo 'Page expires on - ' . trim( implode( ':', $line ) );
    }
}

curl_close( $ch );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it shows at what time it will expires can you make it show the time interval between current and expiry time.